# any pointers for writing plugins in python for fluentd?

Tags: python, fluentd

We are planning to use fluentd for some analytics. Currently I see fluentd by default supports ruby for plugins. Can I write custom plugins in python? Is there anyway to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to do? If you want to write fluentd plugins in Python, there is no way to do that as far as I know. BTW, you can use https://github.com/fluent/fluent-logger-python to send logs to Fluentd from python applications.

Comment: You should refer to platform documentation for this kind of question. If python is not supported, there is no way to write python plugins for it.